# Relations in 3NF format

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

I was doing some textbook questions which contain this following one.

Which of the following relations is in Third normal form (3NF)?

```
a)  R(ABCD) FD's: ABD → C ; CD → A ; AC → B ; AC → D
b)  R(ABCD) FD's: ABD → C ; A → B ; AB → C ; B → A
c)  R(ABCD) FD's: AB → C ; ABD → C ; ABC → D ; AC → D
d)  R(ABCD) FD's: AD → C ; D → A ; A → C ; ABC → D
```

I feel that all four choices are wrong but I do not have the answer to it. Could anybody help me with it?  R represents relationship, FD is short term for functional dependency.

(Disclaimer: this is not from test/homework which gives any credit, I just want to make sure that I understand the concept correctly)

Answer (score 0):

The way to prove something is in a certain NF form is by trying to break it. It is hard to describe why something *is* rather than is not in 3NF. That being said, could you tell me why you think each one does not satisfy 3NF so we can work from there?

This is what I've figured out:
b) Breaks 2NF since candidate key ABD can be broken down into AB which determines non-prime C.
c) Only candidate key is AB. AB -> C. D is determined through a transitive relationship ABC -> D. Breaks 3NF.
d) Candidate key BA determines C. But A -> C, therefore this breaks 2NF.

I could not find anything wrong with a, so that would be my guess to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it in simple words:
Condition for 3NF:

> The **non-prime** attributes should be dependent only on **super key**

For option A,

> **By closure property,**
>
> **AC+=ABCD**

Thus A,C are prime attributes and B,D are non-prime attributes

> Since all non-prime attributes are dependent on super key AC
> The **option A** is in **3NF**

For option  B,

> By closure property,
>
> **ABD+=ABCD**

Thus,A,B,D are prime attributes and C is non-prime attributes

> Since C, a non-prime attribute depends on AC which is not a super key,
>
> option **B** is not in **3NF**

For option C,

> By closure property,
>
> **AB+=ABCD**

Thus,A,B are prime attributes and C,D are non-prime attributes

> Since D a non-prime attribute depends on AC which is not a super key
>
> option **C** is not in 3NF

For option D,

> By closure property,
>
> **AB+=ABCD**

Thus,A,B are prime attributes and C,D are non-prime attribute

> Since C, a non-prime attribute depends on AD which is not a super key,
>
> option **D** is not in **3NF**

Hope,it helps!!